# binary search tree by smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, shared-ptr

I used row pointers to implement the binary search tree data structure and it worked perfectly, but when I replaced the row pointers with shared_ptr it compiles successfully but the program crashes due to unknown run-time error. Could you please help in this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
class node{
public:
int data;
std::shared_ptr<node>left = std::make_shared<node>();
std::shared_ptr<node>right = std::make_shared<node>();
};

std::shared_ptr<node>CreateNode(int x);
void print_tree(const std::shared_ptr<node>&x);

int main(){
    auto root = std::make_shared<node>();
    root = CreateNode(12);
    root->left = CreateNode(9);
    root->right = CreateNode(14);
    root->left->right = CreateNode(10);
    root->left->right = CreateNode(11);
    print_tree(root);
    return 0;
}

std::shared_ptr<node>CreateNode(int x){
    std::shared_ptr<node>NewNode = std::make_shared<node>();
    NewNode->data = x;
    NewNode->left = NewNode->right = nullptr;
    return NewNode;
}

void print_tree(const std::shared_ptr<node>&x){ 
    if(x==nullptr) return;
    std::cout<<x->data<<std::endl;
    print_tree(x->left);
    print_tree(x->right);
}
```

Comment: Each node you create creates infinitely many more nodes, becase each node tries to create both `left` and `right` by itself.

Comment: If ever there was a [explain-to-your-rubber-duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) moment, this is it. The moment you create the root node, it auto-creates a left and right node, each of which create a left and right node, each of which create a left and right node, each of which.... Seeing the problem?

Comment: To fix change `std::shared_ptr<node>left = std::make_shared<node>();` to `std::shared_ptr<node>left;` and do the same for `right`. This way you won't try to create an infinite number of `node`s.

Comment: The essential skill of [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) will identify problems like these.

Comment: @drescherjm That's right! thx it works fine now

Comment: Also `CreateNode` should not modify the members of the new node. Write a `Node(int x)` constructor to initialize the `Node` properly. `CreateNode` then simply becomes `return std::make_shared(x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<node>left;
    std::shared_ptr<node>right;
};

std::shared_ptr<node>CreateNode(int x);
void print_tree(const std::shared_ptr<node>&x);

int main()
{
    auto root = CreateNode(12);
    root->left = CreateNode(9);
    root->right = CreateNode(14);
    root->left->right = CreateNode(10);
    root->left->right = CreateNode(11);
    print_tree(root);
    return 0;
}

std::shared_ptr<node>CreateNode(int x)
{
    std::shared_ptr<node>NewNode = std::make_shared<node>();
    NewNode->data = x;
    NewNode->left = NewNode->right = nullptr;
    return NewNode;
}

void print_tree(const std::shared_ptr<node>&x)
{
    if(x==nullptr) return;
    std::cout<<x->data<<std::endl;
    print_tree(x->left);
    print_tree(x->right);
}
```

This works on my machine. I made `left` and `right` pointers in `node` class initially equal to `nullptr`, instead of creating new node because you can't know is it going to be used. And root to be initialized by result of `CreateNode` function.